# List index out of range when coding a valid move for board game

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hey everyone im new here and im trying to make a game called HiQ now i got the board drawn and everything and i can click on one of the pieces, but when i do the piece does change color and i get an error in the shell as well (listed below) im not sure why im getting this and i was hoping you guys could give me better insight. Ill provide my code below as well and it is coded in python 3, thank you

```
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range

boardcirc =[[0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]]


def HiQ():
    splash_screen() 
    make_board()





def make_board():
    make_sqr()
    make_circ()
    get_click()



def get_click():
    global count, boardcirc
    while 1!=0:
        count = count - 1
        displaymessage("Pieces: " + str(count))        
        where = win.getMouse()
        col = where.x//90
        row = where.y//90
        valid_move(row,col)
        make_move(row,col)




def valid_move(row,col):
    if boardcirc[row][col] == 0:
        return False
    if boardcirc[row-1][col] == 1 and boardcirc[row-2][col] == 1:
        return True
    if boardcirc[row+1][col] == 1 and boardcirc[row+2][col] == 1:
        return True
    if boardcirc[row][col-1] == 1 and boardcirc[row][col-2] == 1:
        return True
    if boardcirc[row][col+1] == 1 and boardcirc[row][col+2] == 1:
        return True



def make_move(row,col):
    while valid_move(row,col) == True:

        col = (col*85)+42
        row = (row*85)+42
        circ = Circle(Point(col,row),35)
        circ.setFill("white")
        circ.draw(win)
```

thats everything that applies to the error

Comment: it helps to include the entire traceback.  but most likely you're doing `col+2` when `col` is large, and ending up with an index beyond the end of the game board.  (`col-2` when `col` is 0 will have a similar problem, but will wrap around instead of causing an error.)

Comment: hey i appreciate the quick response, if you really need the traceback let me know, but im getting the error on the first line of valid_move() 
aka:  if boardcirc[row][col] == 0:

Comment: err well i see you also do `col = (col*85)+42`, which will _definitely_ make `col` and `row` far larger than the size of the board...

Comment: the only reason and use that has is for the size of the pieces to be recolored when it clicks

Comment: but then your `while` loop repeats and passes those very large values into `valid_move` again, where you crash.  maybe you don't want to have a loop there?  maybe you just want an `if`?

Comment: awsome it works now thank you so much ^_^

Answer (score -1):

For your `valid_move(row,col)`, you can't have all those if statements. 
Instead of doing this, use `elif`'s after the initial `if` statement, and don't forget to write an `else` statement

```
if boardcirc[row][col] == 0:
        return False
    if boardcirc[row-1][col] == 1 and boardcirc[row-2][col] == 1:
        return True
    elif boardcirc[row+1][col] == 1 and boardcirc[row+2][col] == 1:
        return True
    elif boardcirc[row][col-1] == 1 and boardcirc[row][col-2] == 1:
        return True
    elif boardcirc[row][col+1] == 1 and boardcirc[row][col+2] == 1:
        return True
else:
    return False
```